# Execute function if document is taller than viewport

Tags: jquery, height, document, viewport

This is some quite strange behaviour I experience. I want to execute a function only when the document is taller than the viewport (i.e. it overflows it and a scrollbar appears). I use this code:

```
var docH = $("document").height(),
    viewPortH = $("window").height();

if (docH > viewPortH) {
 // execute functions
}
```

But nothing happens and console returns:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of null

Does anyone know what the problem is/what code I should use to see whether the document is taller than the viewport?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document` and `window` are objects not selectors.

```
var docH = $(document).height(),
    viewPortH = $(window).height();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the quotes around `document` and `window`.

```
var docH = $(document).height(),
    viewPortH = $(window).height();

if (docH > viewPortH) {
 // execute functions
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/uBCpc/)

With the quotes in place jQuery was actually looking for elements like `<document />` and `<window />` in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

try using document and window like this:
`var docH = $(document).height(),
    viewPortH = $(window).height();`