# If document height is taller than the viewport, perform X

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add some css to an element if the height of the document is taller than the viewport.

```
var docH = $(document).height(),
    viewPortH = $(window).height();

    console.log(docH);
    console.log(viewPortH);

if (docH > viewPortH) {
    $('.slick-slide img').css('max-width', '90%');
}
```

However, `console.log()` outputs both `docH` and `viewPortH` as 733 which is not the case.

I have the `html` set to `height: 100%` and the `body` set to `min-height: 100%`. Is there anything I missed?

I looked over some of the other similar questions here and I seemed to have done everything correctly.

Comment: Strange... I can see no reason why your code wouldn't work. I get the expected values. Can you replicate the problem on jsfiddle?

Comment: this code works for me, does your content cause a scroll bar? look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/wz4jsLcx/embedded/result/

Comment: Maybe check if $(window).height() is bigger than window.screen.availHeight ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute function if document is taller than viewport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231568/execute-function-if-document-is-taller-than-viewport)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code actually seems fine, it should work as expected. Can you make a jsfiddle?

However, have a try with this:

`var docH = parseInt( $('body').prop('scrollHeight') ),`

Comment: I can't make a fiddle because in the fiddle it works lol. I can give you the [live site](http://keebs.com/dax/), though, if that helps. You can see that in the console, the numbers come up the same.

Comment: I see, but `var docH = parseInt( $('body').prop('scrollHeight') ),` should work

Comment: I forgot to mention but I tried that and it didn't work either. The numbers still came up the same. This is really hurting my brain. Thanks for your help and trying anyway.

Comment: maybe youre doing this during the wrong event. put this code in a `$(window).load()` event

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a solution for your problem but may be you could check if the windows has a scrollbar with: `$('#divId').hasScrollBar();` if true than and/modify the css

or

```
var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;

var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                       html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
```

to get the highest part of the [document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/how-to-get-height-of-entire-document-with-javascript)

Comment: I tried this but strangely the numbers are still coming out the same. Here's the [live site](http://keebs.com/dax/). You can see that in the console, the numbers come up the same.